# Determine the value of a Fraction is integer or float in python

Tags: python, fractions

I come across the [Fraction module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) in python. I have problems to determine the result of an integer producting the fraction.

For example, the fraction is `f = Fraction(1, 3)` and when number `n = 2` product with it, the result is `Fraction(2, 3) = 0.666666666...`. When `n=3`, the result shoude be `Farction(3, 3)=1`.

My question is how to distinguish `Fraction(3, 3)` with `Fraction(1,3)`. That's to say the value of a fraction is integer or float? Thanks!

Comment: The `.denominator` attribute of a Fraction will be 1 if and only if it represents an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `f.denominator == 1`, the number is an integer.  Fraction automatically simplifies the number, so `Fraction(3, 3) == Fraction(1, 1)`.